# Powershell script execution failure in Windows

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I have written a powershell script, but when i try to run it, i get an error saying .ps1 file cannot be loaded and It is not digitally signed.

**Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File script.ps1**

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1
```

Comment: I tried Bypass, it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Could you post (copy and paste) exactly the error please?

Comment: File C:\Users\abc\Powershell\Rep.p
s1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\abc\Powershell\Rep.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execut
e on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: um.. maybe some group policy affect your computer? Can you try this script on another computer?

Comment: do you know how to change the group policy?

Comment: @ananthjoshi are you in a domain or stand alone computer?

Answer (score 0):

`Unrestricted` will prompt you with a warning for downloaded files. Try using the executionpolicy `Bypass`. As an alternative, you could go into the properties of the file and unblock the file.

> -- Unrestricted: Loads all configuration files and runs all scripts. *If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the Internet, you are prompted for permission before it runs.
>
> -- Bypass: Nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts.

Source: [Set-ExecutionPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx)

Comment: I tried Bypass, it is still giving me the same error

Comment: What happends if you run it as admin(either using a shortcut or an elevated cmd.exe)?